# Eclipse TCP/IP Monitor has two ports

Tags: eclipse, http, servlets, eclipse-plugin, tcp

I was trying to monitor request using TCP/IP Monitor.

But, I see there are two ports which are in use. One is the application port[8080] and other monitoring port[9833].

Can anybody tell , why there are two different ports?

When I launch the application it launches at 9833 instead of 8080. Why this change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eclipse monitoring is done by capturing all the requests sent to an application (a host and a port), dumping it on the Monitor console for you, then forwarding the original request to the application.
The monitored application itself will return its responses to eclipse (where it is the client from its prospective) where eclipse dumps it on the monitoring console too.

Now, how does eclipse captures the requests sent to the monitored application at the first place? it simply runs a service that accepts these requests (on behalf of the application) and forward it, this service also returns the application responses to the original requester.

Based on the above, in eclipse TCP/IP Monitor screen, the `Local monitoring port` is the port of the **eclipse service** (which you can use any available port number for), and the other `Port` is the monitored **application** port number.

So, in your case, the **application you are monitoring is running on port 8080** and **eclipse service is using the port 9833** (which is just a random port that you can change).

Your application port have not been changed, it still runs on 8080 and you can try that, but no data will be captured by eclipse TCP/IP monitor unless you use the port 9833.

Comment: Thanks I did checked application runs on both the ports, but the 9833 displays the response and 8080 does not. But, can't it done without bringing in the service running at port 9833.

Comment: eclipse service has to run on its own port, and without using that port by the clients there is no way for the monitoring tool to show you the requests/responses.

If you wish to keep the clients using the port 8080, you can temporarily change the application port to something other than 8080 (for tomcat, you can change it from `$CALALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml`) and set the `Local monitoring port` to 8080.

Comment: I tried changing the port from 8080 to 8081 for my application in server.xml, but met with another problem , throwing error 404.